# Как получить результат, при выполнении JUnit?

Tags: java, android

Код который нужнно протестировать

```
    @InjectViewState
public class RegistrationPresenter extends MvpPresenter<IRegistration> {

    @Override
    protected void onFirstViewAttach() {
        super.onFirstViewAttach();

    }

    public void registerUser(String email, String pass){
        try {
            ApiRequest.makeRegister(email, pass)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> {})
                    .doFinally(() -> {})
                    .subscribe(responseBody -> {
                        Log.e("RegistrationPresenter", "registerUser= " + responseBody.toString());
                        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(responseBody.string());
                        getViewState().nextActivity(email, pass, jsonObject.getString("confirm_token"));
                    },Throwable::printStackTrace).dispose();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Код теста, запускаю в JUnit

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void request(){
        RegistrationPresenter registrationPresenter=new RegistrationPresenter();
        registrationPresenter.registerUser("cacaaca@mail.ru", "c3e3e3e");
    }
}
```

---

В итоге я получаю ответ, что тест прошел успешно, но мне нужно было еще и результат получить.

Тоесть строка `Log.e("RegistrationPresenter",` В Тестах не выводиться. Как сделать так чтобы можно было увидеть логи в тестах.
Если так нельзя, то какой смысл вообще в этих тестах, я думал тесты нужны чтобы запускать отдельные модули и методы для проверки и получения результата, а тут такое.....

Comment: Вы с Instrumentation на устройстве запускаете? Есть какойто вывод? (Log.e чисто андроид код в хостовой JVM не должно работать)

Comment: Нет, я запускаю в пакете unitTest. а не androidTest.

Comment: System.out.println тоже не работает.

Comment: Пока сложно сказать что идет не так, дайте вывод gradle test
Для погружения в проблематику рекомендую послушать https://androiddev.apptractor.ru/android-dev-podkast-57/